# Calculating distance of camera in 3D environment

Tags: trigonometry, computer-vision

I have a stage 840x840 px in size.
My viewport is 840x840 px and so is my cube.

I want the face of my cube to fit **exactly** the space of the viewport and so the flash stage.

How can I calculate the camera z distance to accomplish this?

I've came up with something, but still it's not the solution of the problem.
I've analized the situation and came up with this graphic:
[image]

According to this, what I'm looking for is a catethus of a right triangle and, since I've got the other one and the opposite angle degrees, I can use trigonometry to find it.
Still this doesn't work.
In my case the box side is 840 and so is the viewport width, while the camera FOV is 60.

Through trial and error I found the right value for camera.z to be about -591 while using the formula in the image I get -1147.4613391789285
I really don't get what I'm missing.

Hope someone can help me.

Thank you!
Andrea

Comment: Are you sure this a rectilinear camera? Is the FOV diagonal or horizontal?

Comment: These are good questions. I'm checking

Comment: It seems to be vertical

Comment: Which in your case is also horizontal, is it not?

Comment: In the image I made I assumed it was horizontal, yes. Probably my thinking the FOV was a perfect cone is wrong.

Comment: I've not heard of a camera, pinhole or otherwise, with field of vision only 60 degrees.

Comment: @AndreaSilvestri - did my answer help?

Comment: @user45195 - A  20mm lens on a crop body has a ~60 degree HFOV, and a 50mm has a much smaller HFOV, ~26.

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid your calculations are perfectly correct. In general, if half your side length is $c$, the distance from the origin should be:

$$c\left(1+\frac{1}{\tan (\beta)}\right)$$

In your case, assuming a horizontal field of view of $60^\circ$, (i.e. $\beta=30^\circ$), this indeed works out to be around $1147.46$.

The only way the distance could be as small as you suggested is if:

- The field of view of your camera is much larger than you think, $\approx 135^\circ$
- The camera is not using a rectilinear lens, and therefore the pinhole model is incorrect. You would still need to drastically increase the field of view for this to work.
- You are mistaken in regards to the size of the cube. Specifically I suspect that you missed a unit conversion somewhere, since physical objects should be measured in physical units, not pixels.

In case you don't trust the math, here's a blender mock up with a camera distance of $1147.46$, which exactly fits the cube.

$\hskip 2 in$[image]

Comment: Hey sorry for being so sporadic. I thank you for your explanation. I think that the third point of your list is the most possible case. Do you know if there is a way to convert physical units to pixels?

Comment: @AndreaSilvestri - you don't convert physical units to pixels. In the calculation, I assumed that the cube was 840 units across, and therefore the camera must be 1147 units away. The question is, how are you measuring each of those lengths, and are they in the same units or not.

Comment: The problem is: the viewport is in pixels and is 840 px and I want my cube to fit the viewport width (so theorically physical units should match pixels)

Comment: The image size in pixels, yes. But once you set the FOV, that no longer matters. What matters is the cube size (whatever units) and the distance (whatever units).

Comment: let's just say this so: the cube and the viewport has the same ratio

Comment: @AndreaSilvestri - What do you mean by "viewport"? the physical size of the camera's frame doesn't matter at all. What software are you using anyway?

Comment: By Viewport I mean the "window" in which the world is rendered. I'm using various environments: Flash + Away3D and HTML5 + Threejs. Right now I'm on the latter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18368/discussion-between-nbubis-and-andrea-silvestri).